# My original plan was academia. I'm a grad student. I'm uncertain if I want to keep this is my end goal

Tags: graduate-school, career-path, professorship, job-search

I'm posting this here because I frankly am not sure where else to ask a question like this.  If anyone has a better idea where this should go let me know.

I'm a third year American graduate student in a 5 year program in mathematics.  I will be getting my Master's along the way this semester.  For a variety of reasons I will get into below, I've felt ever since I was in high-school that working in higher academia would be an ideal job choice for me.  I've been striving ever since to work towards an eventual tenure-track professorship.  Lately, I've felt less-certain that I will actually enjoy this sort of life-style.

*Why have I felt academia to be a good fit for me?*

1. I usually enjoy math and get a deep-seated pleasure from proving things to be true.  Something about my personality genuinely loves being able to objectively show things.
2. I like the idea of contributing to something large in scope - like an active field of research.
3. I enjoy teaching.  Especially undergraduate level concepts.
4. I have a strong desire to travel.  The idea of going to conferences a lot for my job and potentially doing several post-docs in interesting places along the way appeals to me.  I have nothing to tie me to one place so I can basically settle down wherever the job market will let me.
5. I really don't like workplace drama or the idea of working for some large greedy organization or government.  (Not that frankly I am seeing academia as being too much different in these regards these days.)
6. I don't want what I've learned to go to waste and my skillset to have been "I learned how to problem solve."
7. I like working in overproductive/underproductive cycles.  One week I'll work 20 hours, the next 80.  It's just always the way I've been and academia seems to be more lenient than most places with this kind of thing.
8. I can take summers and winters off besides research.

*Why am I concerned it isn't a good fit for me now?*

1. They say someone getting a graduate degree should be really passionate about what they do.  Sometimes I am and I feel really engaged.  Sometimes I just don't care about what I'm learning, researching, or doing.  I feel less enthused than I did in undergrad.  What if this gets worse and I ultimately end up really disliking my life when I'm many years into my career?
2. I've been having difficulties with anxiety for the last 3 years.  I don't know how much this is other things in my life and how much it is graduate school.  I also don't know how anxiety here will translate to anxiety as a professor or post-doc.  What I do know is that I can't be anxious for the rest of my life.
3. Ultimately, while I'm really lonely having nothing to tie me to one area - it is really nice that I have a lot more freedom in my movement than most people do.  But from everything I hear about the academic job market, I could end up living somewhere I absolutely hate for the rest of my life (which sort of defeats the benefit.)  [This part isn't relevant, but I'd really love to live in Vancouver (or the general Pacific NW), Southern France, Amsterdam, New England, New York, London, Colorado, Tokyo, or New Zealand.]

With this in mind.  I find myself wondering if I wouldn't find another career more appealing.  My personal motivation just isn't what it used to be due to anxiety and depression, and while I could be back to where I was a few years ago again soon - I also could be a lot worse off.  COVID-19 really hasn't helped this either.  I am in contact with barely anyone these days.  I may be a bit of an introvert - but there is a limit to how isolated I want to be.  I've always been so hell-bent on academia that I really have no idea what else could be out there for me.

To get to the point of the post.  I'm looking for opinions on what I should do.  Should I keep going for academia?  Do you know a job market I would like well enough that could be an alternative choice?  One thing is for certain, I need to do something with my education in mathematics.  I have over 80 grand in student debt as well as a serious medical condition (not the mental health, this is something else) and can't afford to just "give it up."  Especially since I have nobody's good will I could fall back on if need be.

Here are some final things that might be relevant:

- I study Number Theory.  I don't do much with cryptography but could probably transition more towards that if needed.
- I'm a first generation college student.  I might seem ignorant, but I just really didn't know anything going into the college system.
- I like the mentor role.   Be it teaching or showing others how to do something, this clicks well with me.
- I'd genuinely be happy so long as I can live life in such a way that I can buy my fancy cheeses and wines, go to orchestras, live in a decent neighborhood with a nearby coffee shop, wear medium range clothes, and visit cool places once in a while.  I don't need a fancy car, or house, or anything like that.  I like splurging on some lower cost items once in a while, but I don't need to be 'raking it in.'
- With a bad health condition its safe to say that I am paranoid about job security.

Sorry for the long post, and thank you for any suggestions you might have.  Ultimately whether I am in in academia or industry, I primarily want a sense of peace, merit to my work, and some vague kind of happiness.

Comment: To be quite honest, I've been questioning whether or not I want to be in academia for a long time also. My reasons are a little more dramatic than yours but overlap quite a lot. Personally I think the ideal way forward is to somehow create a community of math researchers who aren't tied to a university and university nonsense. In my dreams, we would make money by selling organic produce and live in a commune, spending all our free time doing math. Obviously that's far-fetched. I'd love to discuss alternative research lifestyles though.

Comment: Congrats for doing that well as a first generation college student. I am wondering if how you are feeling is related to transitioning from undergrad/coursework (where you as tasked with proving theorems that are known to be true) to navigating unpolished contemporary research works and searching your own questions. If your feelings are related to this, it is very common among math grad students and is part of the research process. Of course, if the anxiety is significant and is impacting your mental health, you should look for professional/medical help.

Comment: Do you have an advisor? Professors are also isolated due to covid and may be happy to chat about anything, for instance your concerns outlined in your question.

Comment: What did you do in undergrad? Is there any prospect for employment based on that? What semi-related hobby activities do you have that could be built on. Example: In my undergrad I learned to do scientific programming (numerical, some symbolic, C program language) on my own time. Then I did particle physics in my grad work.  Then the programming got me my first job in industry.

Comment: What have you done to deal with your anxiety and depression? Probably best to get help with that before making any dramatic life decisions...

Comment: I don’t see any discussion in your post that, even if you do stick with academia, this is an overwhelmingly competitive career route, especially in pure math. Have you considered the likelihood of doing those postdocs in various places and only *then*, at age 35, having to find a new career?

Comment: With regard to your final bullet point, it could be worth considering moving to a country where one's health and medical treatment is not tied to one's job, i.e. some where that's not the USA. You can do that regardless of whether you're working in academia.

Comment: This is too short for an answer, but I think it can point into a productive direction. Your concerns are very valid, BUT will they be less valid outside academia? If you aren't passionate about what you do, have difficulties with anxiety and want to be picky about job location, then you'll have the same troubles in the industry, I believe. Basically, I suggest to cosider whether the alternatives are beneficial in relation to these points.

Comment: @ojfewowmx I do have an advisor.  My advisor is somewhat well known and I don't want them to feel like I'm not interested in their work.  For the most part I am.  That's the primary reason I've avoided talking about this too directly with them.

Comment: @puppetsock I didn't do too much in undergrad.  I worked a little bit with a physics team on some data stuff, and I did some personally-inspired research using module theory, but that's about it.  My hobbies include music and language but that's about it.

Comment: @Dawn I am working on the anxiety and depression.  I think you are right about not making any serious decisions right now - and truthfully I do still have a few years of grad school left after all.  But, asking questions like this now when I have time to contemplate the answers seems wiser than waiting for years.

Comment: @KevinArlin I'm aware its competitive.  I suppose I prefer to ignore that part since there's already a lot of other stressors in grad school.  Perhaps not the wisest choice on my part.  I can't tell if you are warning against or suggesting this path with the postdocs, but I'd be fine with that so long as said "new career" is something I can find then without being out of a job for too long.  On the other hand, there is job security to be concerned with though...

Comment: @astronat I'd really like to do that actually.  (Politics here kind of suck too to be honest.)   Canada feels realistic, but I'd also be happy to move to Europe or Japan.  There's a list of places I'd like to live in the original post.  I have little clue how easy or hard finding a job and relocating to another country is though.  But at least I don't have anything tieing me here as I mentioned before.

Comment: @rg_software I completely agree with that.  That's one of the reasons why as was mentioned by Dawn I should determine how much of this is anxiety and depression based.  Ultimately its not like there is anything I like *better* than what I am doing, and I do at times really love my work.  (I just really don't at times too.)  I am a bit concerned about competitiveness like KevinArlin brought up, but you are right that I don't necessarily see industry as solving most of my problems.  Mostly I asked this question to see what exists that I might be unaware of and alternative perspectives.

Comment: @confusedacademic123 No, my advice was not to go get a couple postdocs and only then leave academia. The problem is that postdocs give you almost no advantage in industry, in particular pure math postdocs. Even starting after a PhD, peers in your generation are already way ahead, and many companies may prefer to hire younger junior employees, especially if your PhD contributes few concrete skills. All these issues are exacerbated by doing postdocs first. My point was, in short, given that academia is such a challenging route to take, if you're doubtful about sticking with it, then don't.

Comment: After getting a PhD I thought I am fed up with university paper projects and spent some time in the industry, but quickly realized they have their own unpleasant factors and decided to move back. I was lucky to get permanently employed quite early though. As a grad student you still can experiment -- get an internship, for example, see how it looks there.

Comment: *With a bad health condition its safe to say that I am paranoid about job security.* - forget academia then. *I really don't like workplace drama* - academia isn't better or worse than other professions in this regard. *I've been having difficulties with anxiety for the last 3 years.* - many people have anxiety, outside and inside academia. Therapy, exercise, good relationships, and meditation are more important than your choice of profession. *Sometimes I just don't care about what I'm learning, researching, or doing.* - like most academics. Passion is a mind state. Mind states change.

Comment: *I've always been so hell-bent on academia that I really have no idea what else could be out there for me.* - You won't know until you try. I worked and traveled for a year before doing my postdoc, hoping that some questions about what I should do with my life would answer themselves. They didn't. But what I gained was first, a fascinating and often fun time in a new country with different people etc. and second, the insight into and later some acceptance of the fact that the big question "what should I do" will just accompany me as long as I'm here.